# Question about a "sexy move" tutorial

Tags: rubiks-cube

I'm using this tutorial to learn solving the cube with "sexy move" - https://sites.google.com/site/cubetutorials101/3x3-rubik-s-cube/3x3-beginner.

It all goes well until the final step where it says "Orient the cube so that the two unsolved corner pieces are on the Front face of the D-layer."

Could someone experienced or familiar with this particular tutorial please take a look and explain to me what it means. My last two unsolved corners are not adjacent, how can they be both on front face and bottom face?

Update: now that the original question is answered, I am trying to complete the rest of the tutorial. It does not work, however. 'Sexy Moves' just scramble the cube cycling to the original 'two corners unsolved' case.

Moreover, I found another very similar tutorial at http://cube.crider.co.uk/beginner.php, which has the same instructions to solve the last two corners.

I tried analyzing the position with Cube explorer - no matter how I orient the cube, no amount of 'sexy move' repetitions solves either of the unsolved corners. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, as a quick fix, I'd recommend doing R' D' R D' R' D2 R D2 and seeing if that brings the corners around. But that might also shuffle the edges, so I don't know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tutorial is incomplete, as it doesn't account for the case you've gotten into. There are a number of ways out of this situation, but using what you already know...

- Position an unsolved corner under the buffer piece. Let `X` denote `(R U R' U')`.
- `X3 D X3 D X3 D2 X3` sets you in the correct position.

This algorithm moves three corners on the bottom layer by one spot in a triangle. Since two needed swapping, the two that are unsolved will be next to each other.

You can then continue the tutorial as written.

Comment: Thank you Emrakul. I must have mixed up one of the X's as I ended up with a scrambled cube after execution of X D X D X D2 X. I tried to do X' D2 X' D' X' X' to get back to my position, but that only proved my point - the cube is still scrambled. I'll try to solve it to the position I was in and check again.

Comment: Would you recommend another tutorial that is complete but still uses a few easy-to-remember algorithms, please?

Comment: @dfo No worries! Algorithms take getting used to. And yeah, this might not be the best tutorial, though it's certainly easy to learn. My advice would be to learn conceptually how the solution works, rather than memorize the algorithms, but that's just my two cents.

Comment: @dfo My apologies, there was actually an error there. I've tested it and the revised alg should work.

Comment: wow, 52 moves just to move a corner to another position... considering the god's number ;)

Comment: In truth, it would be shorter using other algorithms, @dfo :]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22723/discussion-between-dfo-and-emrakul).